# Website for translating weather names and "ice shoves"?

Tags: traduction, terminologie, dictionnaires

I am doing research on ice shoves but the presentation is supposed to be in French which is my second language. I used google translate to translate ice shoves into French, but when I searched the French word up, it gave me something not related to ice shoves. I was wondering if anyone knew a website that translates weather names to the right French word for it, or if anyone knew the French word for ice shoves.

Comment: Could you explain what is "ice shove"?

Comment: G Tr. donne _glissades de glace_ (!) pour le terme. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the online terminology database of the World Meteorological Organisation, it provides translations of terms from English to French:

[Meteoterm](https://www.wmo.int/pages/prog/lsp/meteoterm_wmo_en.html)

Unfortunately, "ice shove" is not in it. Although it is not a common phrase, you can translate it as "vague gelée", such as in [this article](http://www.sudouest.fr/2018/01/06/des-photos-spectaculaires-de-vagues-gelees-aux-etats-unis-4088515-4776.php).

Comment: Also "vague de glace" could be used.

Answer (score 1):

En règle générale, je cherche le terme technique dont j'ai besoin d'une traduction dans le Wikipedia anglophone et je clique sur la rubrique *Français* pour changer de langue.

Dans ce cas précis, [Ice shove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_shove) ne donne rien en français. Mais le lien espagnol donne [Ivu](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivu) qui est aussi donné comme synonyme sur la page anglophone. C'est peut-être le terme consacré dans la langue d'une contrée habituée à ce genre de phénomène.

À défaut, on peut aussi se contenter de la traduction d'un autre des synonymes: *Ice tsunami* qui donnerait *Tsunami de glace*. D'ailleurs, en cherchant cette dernière expression, on tombe sur [une dépêche de France Info sur le phénomène](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/monde/ameriques/vagues-de-glace-dans-les-grands-lacs-un-phenomene-exceptionnel_323224.html) (où ils parlent aussi de *vagues de glace*):

> Francetv info  : Ce phénomène a-t-il un nom ?
>
> Etienne Kapikian : Je n'en ai pas trouvé en français. Aux Etats-Unis,
>   ils l'ont appelé "ice tsunami", le tsunami de glace, mais il ne s'agit
>   pas d'un nom scientifique. On trouve aussi "lake ice drift" (glace de
>   lac à la dérive). En français, on pourrait dire : submersion des
>   littoraux par de la glace de lac.

Comment: Ce fut une recherche intéressante mais au final je me demande vraiment si le phénomène auquel on réfère sur CNN ds. l'article _Ice Shove_ (vidéo ds. ma réponse à _saisissantes_) correspond au phénomène classique ou non... je ne suis pas qualifié pour traiter du sujet... votre réponse m'a été particulièrement utile. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

Concernant les *ice shoves* dans le domaine de la glaciologie on trouve au *Termium* une panoplie de termes (et entre crochets suivent les sources sur lesquelles chacun s'appuie) :

> [Poussée des glaces](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pouss%C3%A9e%20des%20glaces&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpouss%C3%A9e%20des%20glaces%3B%2Cc0) [Bureau de la trad., Internet x 2]
>  Poussée
>   glacielle [*Dictionnaire de géomorphologie* (Genest)]
>  Poussée de
>   gel [*Dictionnaire des sciences et techniques du pétrole* (Moureau)] 
>   Poussée due au glaces [Bureau de la trad. (antérieur)]
>  [Pression
>   des glaces](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pression%20des%20glaces&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpression%20des%20glaces%3B%2Cc0) [*Terminologie de la glace de rivière et de lac*
>   (Drouin)]
>
> [ [TERMIUM (banque de données terminologiques et linguistiques du
>   gouvernement du Canada)](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=ICE%20SHOVE) ]

Le phénomène s'apparente techniquement à celui des *icebergs* (nous dit [Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_shove) dans l'article déniché dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/28939)), dont les manifestations causent des dommages par raclage, et vue la poussée latérale de cette glace chevauchant la berge, et non au [*tsunami*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8869636), une onde qui cause une vague qu'on désigne couramment de la même manière par métonymie, se déplaçant généralement à grande vitesse et non au ralenti, même si certaines manifestations de ce qu'on associe aux *ice shoves* sont [saisissantes](https://youtu.be/0EyfEDKWscg). On trouve la [*poussée de glace*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8481817) au *GDT* associée au terme *ice push*, [synonyme](https://books.google.com/books?id=yD79FqfECCYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Glossary%20of%20geology%20/%20Robert%20L.%20Bates&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-ofXyx4PZAhUh3YMKHTeAAJ8Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22ice%20shove%22&f=false) apparaîssant avec *ice shoves* au *Termium*, dans le domaine de l'eau, avec une référence à la *pression de la glace*. On a donc possiblement aussi, comme avec le mot *tsunami*, un emploi identique pour la nature du phénomène et pour ses manifestations... Un terme comme [*ice ride-up*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&index=frt&srchtxt=POUSSEE%20GLACE%20BERGES) accorde peut-être plus d'importance à l'idée du *chevauchevement de la glace sur les berges*. Pour l'amoncellement qui cause l'obstruction de cours d'eau ou sur des lacs, pouvant résulter en des conséquences similaires à ce dont on vient de discuter, on verra plus généralement l'[*embâcle*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26522620) ([*glaciel*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emb%C3%A2cle_de_glace))...